# Get message-id with Laravel Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4

Is there a way to get the message-id of the to be send email within Laravel Mailables?

I currently get the id like this which just works fine, but since this doesn't support markdowns and stuff, I would prefer to get around this:

```
Mail::send('mail.contact.confirmation', $contactData, function (Message $message) use ($mailTo, $subject, &$headers)
{
    $headers['message-id'] = $message->getSwiftMessage()->getId();
    $message->to($mailTo)->subject($subject);
});
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had to figure this out on my own, so take my answer with a grain of salt (although it works for me).

Within the "build()" function of a Laravel Mailable, you can do:

```
$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($swiftmessage) {
   echo $swiftmessage->getId();
});
```

Hopefully that gets you started. My use-case was editting the ID, so I used:

```
$this->withSwiftMessage(function ($swiftmessage) use ($newId) {
  $swiftmessage->setId($newId);
  return $swiftmessage;
});
```

Comment: Seems good, sorry for the late response. It's kinda the same hackish thing that I did before. But if it works, it ain't stupid :)

Comment: Is this still working with Laravel 5.6? I've tried that too, but in my case it's always empty. My command is only a little bit different, but this shouldn't matter, right? `Mail::to(Auth::user()->email)->queue(new Order($order_id));`

Comment: I can confirm: This solution is still working with Laravel 5.6.

Comment: I  am currently doing the same thing and my messageId is not getting extracted. I read somewhere that setting or  replacing the messageID depends on the mail server used. What would be the best way to tackle this problem? Would setting the message Id (just like you did) solve my  problem? I also tried listening to MessageSent event with no  results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge where I had to run a `Laravel` Queue where **message ID** should be displayed after sending an email. I solved this issue like this.

namespace App\Jobs

**inside handle()**

```
$message_Id="";
Mail::send('emails.thanks',array(),function($message) use(&$message_Id){
$message_Id=$message->getId();
$message->to('enter email id','any name')->subject('Please check the message ID');
});
echo $message_id;
```